# Add lines to 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I add lines that demarcate the different regions of the following 3D plot:

```
Plot3D[1/(1 + E^(-a - c)), {a, -8, 8}, {c, -8, 8}]
```

To give you an idea of what I have in mind I have added the lines and descriptions in the 3D plot in paint; now I want to know how to do it directly in *Mathematica*.

[image]

Comment: [**Crossposted here**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/174919)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`MeshFunctions` are generally quite useful for making such demarcations:

```
With[{d = {Thick, Yellow}},
    Plot3D[1/(1 + E^(-a - c)), {a, -8, 8}, {c, -8, 8}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
        MeshStyle -> {Black, Black, d, d, d}, Mesh -> {10, 10, {0}, {0}, {0}}, 
        MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, # &, If[# <= 0, # + #2] &, If[# <= 0, #2] &}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I was working on MeshFunctions too, but couldn't get the function definitions quite right. Didn't know that the If's without second argument could work here.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm not sure that they do.  Try permuting the order of the mesh functions.  When one `If` returns a `Null`, mesh functions later in the list are messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Sorry for crossposting (I did not anticipate that you would be so quick and effective in replying!)