# Add Point to Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I'd like to simply add a nice thick point in $(0,0,0)$ to `Plot3D[(y^2/x), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]`.

The solutions I came across to add anything to `Plot3D`, mostly involved [MeshFunctions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39408/add-lines-to-3d-plot). However I don't see how I could manipulate the mesh to give the desired result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Show` and add `Graphics3D[{PointSize@.5, Point[{0,0,0}]}]`. And welcome to Mathematica.SE :)

Comment: closely related: [add point to existing graphic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1675/5478)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Show[
  Plot3D[(y^2/x), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.1], Point[{0, 0, 0}]}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be an overkill but it is useful (no joke!) cause when you export points and lines they [tend to look odd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30507/how-to-properly-project-a-graphics-object-consisting-of-line-primitives) the thicker they are. You can fake a red point by re-difining your `ColorFunction` like so:

```
With[{colf = Function[{x, y, z},
    If[Norm@{x, y} < .15,
     Red,
     ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][z]]]},
(* Define a color function that is red within some radius (here 0.15) and something else outside*)
 Plot3D[(y^2/x), {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},  
  ColorFunction -> colf, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotPoints -> 80]
 ]
```

and the result will not suffer from the problems that a thick point would have:

[image: re point]