# Why Plot3D does not accept Epilog option

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am trying to visualize 3D points with Plot3D using the option Epilog.
If you check the options of Plot3D ( `Options[Plot3D]` ), it can be seen that Epilog is one of the options of Plot3D. But when implementing this option not result as expected.
for example:

```
  data = Flatten[
  Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^2}, {i, -2, 2, .5}, {j, -2, 2, .5}], 1];
    Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Of course there is another ways (like using `Show`), but the question is why Plot3D does not accept its own option?

Comment: "In three-dimensional graphics, two-dimensional graphics primitives can be specified by the Epilog option. The graphics primitives are rendered in a 0,1 coordinate system": `Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{.5, .5}]}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @kuba Still the points are in the {x,y} plan. I am looking to have the points in 3D. you can see the difference between Show[ListPointPlot3D[
  Table[{i, j, i^2 + j^2}, {i, -2, 2, .1}, {j, -2, 2, .1}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]], 
 Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]] and  Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], 
   Point[Table[{i, j}, {i, -2, 2, .1}, {j, -2, 2, .1}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

Comment: @Algohi If you want a point, just use `Show` and `Graphics3D[Point@something]`.

Comment: closely related: [41439](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41439/5478)

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41439/add-point-to-plot3d) for example- as *Öskå* said, use `show`...

Comment: @Öskå it is easier to use show[plot3d and listpoinplot3d]. I am just wandering why plot3d does not accept its own option.

Comment: @Algohi At least with `Graphics3D` you can do more than just points ;)

Comment: @Öskå  Yes, Graphics3D can do more than just points :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Why does `Plot3D` not accept its own option?

But it does accept it just fine, as Kuba's comment shows:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Point[{.5, .5}]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I guess you mean to ask,

> Why does `Plot3D` not accept 3D graphics in `Epilog`?

Because `Epilog` is for drawing things *in front of* the plot, just as `Prolog` is for drawing things *behind* the plot. So, the ordering is: a flat 2D layer for `Prolog`, then the 3D plot, then a flat 2D layer for `Epilog`. (Like a sandwich... mmm.) If `Epilog` accepted 3D graphics, then they would exist in the same space as the plot itself, and would not always appear in front.

(Actually, Mathematica could in principle allow 3D graphics in `Epilog` by rendering them with the same viewpoint but on a separate buffer and then compositing the result on top of the plot, so that you would always see them even when they are geometrically behind the plot. But I imagine that would be rarely useful and often confusing.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the question and for explaining how Epilog works :)

Comment: You just had to use the sandwich analogy… mmm, sandwich. (+1, of course.)