# How do I put a data point in a 3D graph? I need it in (0,0,1)

Tags: plotting, graphics

This is what I have now

```
Clear[x, y, f]; ​​
f[x_, y_] = E^(-x^2+y);

surface = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]; 
threedims = Axes3D[3];
datapoint = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0,0,1}]}];

Show[threedims, datapoint,surface, ViewPoint -> CMView, PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False]​
```

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41439/add-point-to-plot3d

Comment: I don't know the command `Axes3D`; I am also unfamiliar with the `CMView` option value for `ViewPoint`. Are you using some special plotting package?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Graphics` with `Graphics3D`.

Also, note that you might prefer the result using `Sphere` instead of `Point`.

```
datapoint = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I suppose you meant `Point` rather than `Dot`.

Comment: @MarcoB right, edited.

Answer (score 3):

This is an extended comment on anderstood's answer, which basically correct. However, some changes in details are in order.

Better to define your function with SetDelayed ( := ).

```
f[x_, y_] := E^(-x^2 + y)
```

The plot theme "NoAxes" is the easy way to get rid of both axes and bounding box. Also, making sure surface is not clipped.

```
surface = 
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
   PlotRange -> All,
   PlotTheme -> {"NoAxes", "ZMesh"}];
```

The directive `PointSize` has no effect on spheres and so is not needed.

```
datapoint = Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 1}, .1]}];

Show[surface, datapoint, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

The above code produces

[image: plot]