# How can I show the extremum clearly in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting

```
 p11[x_, δ_, b11_] := 1/x^4 + (2 b11)/x^2 + 4/x - 4 b11 x - 
  1/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(4/3) - (
  2 b11)/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(2/3) - 
  4/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(1/3) + 
  4 b11 (1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(1/3)
Plot3D[p11[x, 0.01, b11]/0.01, {x, 1, 4}, {b11, 0, 0.5}, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, b11, p}, Mesh -> 5, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Black,
  ViewPoint -> {-1.2, -2, 1.5}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 2, 4}, Automatic, {5, 10}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Q:I want to show the maximum(or the peak) in red color, and the minmum(or the Valley) in blue.

color the local maximum region and the local minimum region

I want to see the location of the vally in colors, and how it changes with b11. I wonder if `ColorFunction` can do this? Can MMA color the nearby area of local extreme value in different color with others?

[image]

just like this

[image]

The extremum can be found like this `Abs[D[p11[x, 0.01, b11], x]]=0`.

Comment: You could use something like `Show[(* plot *), Graphics3D[{{Red, Sphere[(* max location *), 0.02]}, {Blue, Sphere[(* min location *), 0.02]}}]]`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! But  I want to know how the function p[]-x change with b11 from 3Dplot, not the number solutions.

Comment: Now what you sought, but I prefer:  `ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"`.

Comment: Related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94595

Comment: You don't have local extrema in the regions you outline

Answer (score 3):

```
p3d = Plot3D[p11[x, 0.01, b11]/0.01, {x, 1, 4}, {b11, 0, 0.5}, 
     Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, b11, p}, Mesh -> 5, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
     AxesStyle -> Black, ViewPoint -> {-1.2, -2, 1.5}, 
     Ticks -> {{0, 2, 4}, Automatic, {5, 10}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}];

{min, max} = #[p3d[[1, 1]], Last] & /@ {MinimalBy, MaximalBy};
Show[p3d, Graphics3D[{PointSize[.05], Blue, Point@ First @ min, Red, Point@ First @ max}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Better to use Sphere than Point in 3D don't you think?

Comment: @m_goldberg, I agree; but plain `Sphere` gives ellipsoids, and felt lazy to find the right values for the second argument:)

Comment: In such cases I use Ellipsoid to adjust the markers to spherical.

Comment: Sorry about my bad description, I just redescribe the question. Can MMA color the nearby area of local extreme value in different color just like the third picture?

Answer (score 3):

The plot really looks better with spheres marking the extrema. And since kglr doesn't want to take the time to write the code to make such markers, I will will supply it.

```
p11[x_, δ_, b11_] := 
  1/x^4 + (2 b11)/x^2 + 4/x - 4 b11 x - 1/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(4/3) - 
  (2 b11)/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(2/3) - 4/(1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(1/3) + 
  4 b11 (1 + (-1 + x^3) (1 + δ)^3)^(1/3)

surface = 
  Plot3D[p11[x, 0.01, b11]/0.01, {x, 1, 4}, {b11, 0, 0.5},
    Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, b11, p}, Mesh -> 5, 
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
    AxesStyle -> Black, ViewPoint -> {-1.2, -2, 1.5}, 
    Ticks -> {{0, 2, 4}, Automatic, {5, 10}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]

{min, max} = 
  Chop[#[surface[[1, 1]], Last] & /@ {MinimalBy, MaximalBy}, 10^-5][[All, 1]]

extrema =
  With[{r = .03 (max - min)}, 
    Graphics3D[{Blue, Ellipsoid[min, r], Red, Ellipsoid[max, r]}]];

Show[surface, extrema, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

`r` is computed from the formula

```
 r = scaleFactor {xRange, yRange, zRange} = scaleFactor (max - min)
```

where `scalarFactor` is picked by eye.