# Draw Lines on 3D Plot at certain coordinate

Tags: plotting, mesh

[Following this example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39408/add-lines-to-3d-plot), I though it would be as easy as this:

```
Plot3D[1/(x^2 + 1) + 1/(y^2 + 1), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
MeshStyle -> {Black, Black, Red, Green}, Mesh -> {20, 20, 20, 20}, 
MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, If[# == 5, #] &, If[#2 == 5, #2] &}]
```

However, this shows only the black mesh. I played around with the number parameter in `Mesh->` But that didn't help. How can I draw a red/green line over the plot at a certain x or y position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot3D[1/(x^2 + 1) + 1/(y^2 + 1), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 MeshStyle -> {Black, Black, Red, Green}, Mesh -> {20, 20, {5}, {2}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, # &, #2 &}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can specify the mesh divisions for the third and fourth mesh functions as  lists of `{division, style}` pairs:

```
Plot3D[1/(x^2 + 1) + 1/(y^2 + 1), {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
 MeshStyle -> Black, Mesh -> {20, 20, {{5, Red}}, {{2, Green}}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, # &, #2 &}]
```

> same picture

Comment: Sometimes it can be as easy as that